# Rendering hundreds of datas : lazy loading, partial rendering?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I can seem to find a good answer for my problem. I have a sidebar template which contains a div for each item my model contains. When I have hundreds of items to render, it takes up to 8-10 seconds to render the template. I am using ember-data.

How can I render the items that are loaded before it finishes fetching the entire model?

Here is my template :

```
{{#each conv in model itemController='singleconv'}}
        {{#if (equals conv.url selectedSubuserEmail)}}
            <div class="conversation-content-wrapper" {{action "clickConv" conv preventDefault=false}}>
                    <div class="history-message-assigned in-progress-closed" style="display:none;"><p><i class="icon-x"></i>Conversation closed</p></div>
                    <div class="history-message-assigned in-progress-assignation" style="display:none;"><p><i class="icon-assign"></i>Conversation assigned</p></div>
                    <div class="history-message-assigned in-progress-reopen" style="display:none;"><p><i class="icon-re-opened"></i>Conversation re-opened</p></div>          
                <div class={{conv.selectedClass}}>          
                    <div class="conversation-time-history">{{{conv.status}}}</div>
                    <div class="conversation-details">
                        <span class="unread-numbers"></span>
                            {{input type='checkbox' class='chk-conversation' checked=conv.isChecked}}
                             <span class="conversation-name">{{conv.customer.name}}</span>
                             <span class="phone-number">{{conv.customer.cellPhoneNumber}}</span>
                            <p class="conversation-text">{{conv.lastMessage}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>                       
            </div>
        {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the main problem in ember's rendering which is getting much better by time, Ember connects all your binding to your created models so it re-renders the view on every added model, and hence the delay.

And I've been in the same situation, you have a couple of solutions here

**1- Using Ember.ListView**

You can use [Ember list-view](http://emberjs.com/list-view/) which is an Ember plug-in that adds lazy rendering to a List of items, very useful if you have items that can be displayed in the same height in pixels.

**2- Using Ember Cloaking**

[Ember Cloaking](https://github.com/eviltrout/ember-cloaking/) is about the same as list-view but has flexible heights, although you still need to compute them before rendering.

**3- Using visibility checker like `waypoints`**

I've done this myself and its a little tedious but plug-in free none the less

You create a variable in your component that is set to true when it's visible in the waypoint.

sample code, not a real one

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
   visible:false,
   didInsertElement:function() {
      var waypoint = new Waypoint({
         element: this.$()[0],
         handler: function(direction) {
           this.set('visibile',true)
        }.bind(this)
      })
   }
})
```

Then Move your content into this component

And then inside this component:

```
{{#if visibile}}
   <div class="conversation-content-wrapper" {{action "clickConv" conv preventDefault=false}}>
                    <div class="history-message-assigned in-progress-closed" style="display:none;"><p><i class="icon-x"></i>Conversation closed</p></div>
                    <div class="history-message-assigned in-progress-assignation" style="display:none;"><p><i class="icon-assign"></i>Conversation assigned</p></div>
                    <div class="history-message-assigned in-progress-reopen" style="display:none;"><p><i class="icon-re-opened"></i>Conversation re-opened</p></div>          
                <div class={{conv.selectedClass}}>          
                    <div class="conversation-time-history">{{{conv.status}}}</div>
                    <div class="conversation-details">
                        <span class="unread-numbers"></span>
                            {{input type='checkbox' class='chk-conversation' checked=conv.isChecked}}
                             <span class="conversation-name">{{conv.customer.name}}</span>
                             <span class="phone-number">{{conv.customer.cellPhoneNumber}}</span>
                            <p class="conversation-text">{{conv.lastMessage}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>                       
            </div>
{{/if}}
```

and then the "for-each" block

```
{{#each conv in model itemController='singleconv'}}
    {{the-component conv=conv}}
{{/each}}
```

Then use a counter or something to make the first 10 visible.

As I said this is only a simple example you can dig more into it.

Comment: I found a way to do what I wanted by setting up my rails backend with a query param refreshing my model. In rails : I set an offset from this parameter and limited to 10 the number of conversations fetched. When I trigger a certain action (example end of scrolling or click on button "More'") I set the new value of this param which retriggers a server call (using my model hook) along with the now increased parameter. Keep in mind that ember-data doesn't load datas that already are in the store so it only queries 10 at a time and puts them into cache.

Comment: Yes of course you could use pagination, the suggestion was for displaying the data all at once, there is also ember-infinity add on for infinite scrolling